# Redirecting to 404 page not found - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, routes

I need to redirect incorrect pages to the 404 page, currently I'm redirecting to the homepage and I have this:

```
def thirdlevel
    if something
      if something else
        render :template => "services/thirdlevel"
      else
         redirect_to "/"
      end
    else
    redirect_to "/"
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added the error404 action to my controller and then referenced it that way:

```
else
  render :action => "error404"
end


def error404
  @breadcrumb = [{:name => "Page not found"}]
end
```

Comment: -1. Error 404 pages should return a 404 error in the HTTP header and using a breadcrumb to show that a page doesn't exist, is not a good practice in general.